# ¿Como puedo hacer uso de un método de un activity, en un fragment de otro activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy realizando una aplicacion que tiene un login como activity principal, al ingresar como invitado abre un navigation drawer y en este menú te da la opción de registrarte y quiero hacer uso de un método ConsultarDatos que esta en la clase del login, en mi botón agregar registro dentro del fragment.

Comment: Si no estoy equivocado, lo que buscas es esto '((ClaseMetodo)getActivity()).elMetodo();'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si el fragment no pertenece a ese activity pero aun así necesitas llamar al método, lo mejor es que extraigas el método a otra clase, para que ambos (el activity y el fragment) puedan usarlo.

Hacerlo estático o algo parecido me parece un diseño bastante frágil.

Por otra parte, si el fragmento pertenece a ese activity, puedes hacer un cast y usar el método, tal y como han dicho en otras respuestas:

```
((ClaseLogin)getActivity()).consultarDatos();
```

Answer (score 0):

Partiendo de la base que un Fragment debe pertenecer a una Actividad y un Fragment no tiene un Contexto, llamando a la actividad a la que pertenece ya se podría utilizar ese método.

```
((ClaseLogin)getActivity()).consultarDatos();
```